# Problema customizando puntuación con estrellas

Tags: javascript

Estoy haciendo un sistema de encuesta en laravel, al publicar la encuesta, tengo campos que quiero sean de "valoración o puntuación" a través de estrellas, conseguí implementar ésta función utilizando el código de codexworld_rating_widget

```js
/*
 * Star Rating
 * by CodexWorld
 *
 * More info:
 * http://www.codexworld.com
 *
 * Copyright 2015 CodexWorld
 * Released under the MIT license
 * 
 */
console.log("llamado al archivo");
(function(a){
    a.fn.codexworld_rating_widget = function(p){
    //$.fn.codexworld_rating_widget  = function(p){   
        console.log("llamado a la funcion");
        var p = p||{};
        var b = p&&p.starLength?p.starLength:"5";
        var c = p&&p.callbackFunctionName?p.callbackFunctionName:"";
        var e = p&&p.initialValue?p.initialValue:"0";
        var d = p&&p.imageDirectory?p.imageDirectory:"images";
        var r = p&&p.inputAttr?p.inputAttr:"";
        var f = e;
        var g = a(this);
        b = parseInt(b);
        init();
        g.next("ul").children("li").hover(function(){
            $(this).parent().children("li").css('background-position','0px 0px');
            var a = $(this).parent().children("li").index($(this));
            $(this).parent().children("li").slice(0,a+1).css('background-position','0px -28px')
        },function(){});
        g.next("ul").children("li").click(function(){
            var a = $(this).parent().children("li").index($(this));
            var attrVal = (r != '')?g.attr(r):'';
            f = a+1;
            g.val(f);
            if(c != ""){
                eval(c+"("+g.val()+", "+attrVal+")")
            }
        });
        g.next("ul").hover(function(){},function(){
            if(f == ""){
                $(this).children("li").slice(0,f).css('background-position','0px 0px')
            }else{
                $(this).children("li").css('background-position','0px 0px');
                $(this).children("li").slice(0,f).css('background-position','0px -28px')
            }
        });
        function init(){
            $('<div style="clear:both;"></div>').insertAfter(g);
            g.css("float","left");
            var a = $("<ul>");
            a.addClass("codexworld_rating_widget");
            for(var i=1;i<=b;i++){
                a.append('<li style="background-image:url('+d+'/widget_star.gif)"><span>'+i+'</span></li>')
            }
            a.insertAfter(g);
            if(e != ""){
                f = e;
                g.val(e);
                g.next("ul").children("li").slice(0,f).css('background-position','0px -28px')
            }
        }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.codexworld_rating_widget{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    float: left;
}
.codexworld_rating_widget li{
    line-height: 0px;
    width: 28px;
    height: 28px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    margin-left: 2px;
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.codexworld_rating_widget li span{
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title> Encuesta </title>
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/vendor/adminlte/vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/vendor/adminlte/vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- Ionicons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/vendor/adminlte/vendor/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
    <!-- Select2 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://localhost/vendor/adminlte/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
    <!-- DataTables with bootstrap 3 style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.css">
    <!-- Google Font -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition ">
<link href="http://localhost/css/rating.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<section class="content-header" >
    <h1>Encuesta</h1>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>Administración</a></li>
        <li class="active">Aplicar Encuesta</li>
    </ol>
</section>
<section class="content" style="width: 70%">
    <div class="box box-success" style="padding:30px;" id="myform">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="card card-warning">
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">Encuesta Uno</div>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="http://localhost/encuestas/registrar_resultados" accept-charset="UTF-8"><input name="_token" type="hidden" value="bsr97fZbFLX4rNt4YhcWtVpTWhuYyiD9OcuHf05W">
                    <input name="id_encuesta" type="hidden" value="20">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="bsr97fZbFLX4rNt4YhcWtVpTWhuYyiD9OcuHf05W">
                    <div class="answers" id="poll">
                        <ol class="answers-list">
                            <div id="buildyourform">
                                <div class="fieldwrapper" id="padre_field1">1.pregunta uno
                                    <input  type="hidden" name="encuesta.id_preguntas[]" value="35">
                                </div>
                                    1<input type="checkbox" id="65" name="encuesta.id_opciones[35][65]" value="65" />
                                    2<input type="checkbox" id="66" name="encuesta.id_opciones[35][66]" value="66" />
                                    3<input type="checkbox" id="67" name="encuesta.id_opciones[35][67]" value="67" />
                                                                                                                   
                                <div class="fieldwrapper" id="padre_field2">2.pregunta dos
                                    <input  type="hidden" name="encuesta.id_preguntas[]" value="36">
                                </div>
                                    a<input type="checkbox" id="68" name="encuesta.id_opciones[36][68]" value="68" />
                                    b<input type="checkbox" id="69" name="encuesta.id_opciones[36][69]" value="69" />
                                    c<input type="checkbox" id="70" name="encuesta.id_opciones[36][70]" value="70" />
                                    d<input type="checkbox" id="71" name="encuesta.id_opciones[36][71]" value="71" />
                                
                                <div class="fieldwrapper" id="padre_field3">3.pregunta tres
                                    <input  type="hidden" name="encuesta.id_preguntas[]" value="37">
                                </div>
                                        
                                <input type="hidden" class="valor_id_37" name="encuesta.id_opciones[76]" value="" id="valor_id_opciones_37"/>
                                <input class="rating_star"  value="0" id="opciones_37" type="hidden" postID="3" data-pregunta="37"  />
                                <input value="5" id="estrellas" type="hidden" name="encuesta.estrellas[]" data-pregunta="37" />
                                               
                                <div class="fieldwrapper" id="padre_field4">4.sugerencias
                                    <input  type="hidden" name="encuesta.id_preguntas[]" value="38">
                                </div>
                                        
                                <textarea id="77" name="encuesta.id_opciones[77]" ></textarea>
                                <div class="fieldwrapper" id="padre_field5">5.pregunta abierta
                                    <input  type="hidden" name="encuesta.id_preguntas[]" value="39">
                                </div>
                                <textarea id="78" name="encuesta.id_opciones[78]" ></textarea>
                                <div class="fieldwrapper" id="padre_field6">6.califique
                                    <input  type="hidden" name="encuesta.id_preguntas[]" value="40">
                                </div>
                                        
                                <input type="hidden" class="valor_id_40" name="encuesta.id_opciones[82]" value="" id="valor_id_opciones_40"/>
                                <input class="rating_star"  value="0" id="opciones_40" type="hidden" postID="6" data-pregunta="40"  />
                                <input value="4" id="estrellas" type="hidden" name="encuesta.estrellas[]" data-pregunta="40" />
                                               
                                <div class="fieldwrapper" id="padre_field7">7.text
                                    <input  type="hidden" name="encuesta.id_preguntas[]" value="41">
                                </div>
                                
                                Campo texto <input type="textbox" id="83" name="encuesta.id_opciones[83]" value="" />
                                                                                                                   
                            </div>
                        </ol>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Guardar</button>
                    </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(function() {
        
        $(".rating_star").codexworld_rating_widget({
            //starLength: '1', //Estrellas que se van a mostrar. Por defecto 5.
            starLength: $('#estrellas').val(), 
            initialValue: '',  //Valor de votación cuando el documento se carga por primera vez. Por defecto 0.
            callbackFunctionName: 'processRating', //Función a la cual se llamará cuando se clique alguna estrella.
            imageDirectory: "http://localhost/imagenes",  //Nombre del directorio de la imagen de la estrella. Por defecto 'images'
            inputAttr: 'postID'   //Valor que se le pasa a la función de devolución, si es que la hay.
        });
    });

    function processRating(val, attrVal){
        var id_pregunta = $('#estrellas').data("pregunta");
        var des_opciones = val;
        var token = $("input[name='_token']").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '../getIdOpcionesAjax',
            data:  {id_pregunta:id_pregunta, des_opciones:des_opciones, _token:token},
            success : function(data) {
                //alert(data);
                if (data > 0 ) {
                    $("#valor_id_opciones_"+id_pregunta).val(data);
                }
            }
        });
    }

</script>


<script src="http://localhost/vendor/adminlte/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/vendor/adminlte/vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://localhost/vendor/adminlte/vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Select2 -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>

    <!-- DataTables with bootstrap 3 renderer -->
    <script src="//cdn.datatables.net/v/bs/dt-1.10.18/datatables.min.js"></script>

    <!-- ChartJS -->
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.0/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Calificación con estrellas para encuestas -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost/js/rating.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero al intentar customizar ésto para tener mas de un campo de valoración con estrellas, termina sustituyendo siempre el valor del campo 1, es decir que no actualiza el valor correpondiente al campo actual asociado con ésa valoración sino que siempre me llama al primer campo de la clase rating_star.
Cómo customizo ésto correctamente para emparejar el resultado con su campo de valoración correspondiente? 
Gracias

Comment: no es familiar la libreria pero lo que entiendo es que quieres que puedan calificar la encuestas con estrellas?

Comment: Si, el asunto es que la librería que estoy usando está hecha para un solo campo de valoración por encuesta y yo estoy considerando tener mas de un campo con éstas características en mi encuesta.

Comment: creo que esto te puede ayudar https://codepen.io/depy/pen/vEWWdw

Comment: Es importante muestres el código que has logrado (el customizado) para poder ayudarte donde debes ajustarlo.

Comment: Gracias, voy a intentarlo

Comment: @fwBasic ése es el customizado

Comment: @Virginia, el ejemplo que publicas no es funcional, es decir no muestra estrella en ningún campo, debes hacer que el ejemplo muestre la estrella en el primer campo (tal como lo especificas en tu comentario) y asi poder hacer un seguimiento al problema.